# Scipy LeastSq errorbars

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I'm fitting an experimental spectrum to a theoretical expectation using LeastSq from SciPy. There are of course errors associated with the experimental values. How can I feed these to the LeastSq or do I need a different routine? I find nothing in the documentation.

Comment: Are they errors from data formats (e.g. "null" ) or [outliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) ? In the latter case, there are no standard way to deal with it.

Comment: Can you give more detail on the error content and the distribution of errors?

Comment: The errors are basically the sqrt of the number of counts in a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [scipy.optimize.leastsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) function does not have a built-in way to incorporate weights. However, the [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) function does have a `sigma` parameter which can be used to indicate the variance of each y-data point.

`curve_fit` uses `1.0/sigma` as the weight, where `sigma` can be an array of length `N`, (the same length as `ydata`).

So somehow you have to surmise the variance of each ydata point based on the size of the error bar and use that to determine `sigma`.

For example, if you declare that half the length of the error bar represents 1 standard deviation, then the variance (what `curve_fit` calls `sigma`) would be the square of the standard deviation.

```
sigma = (length_of_error_bar/2)**2
```

Reference:

- [Wikipedia page on Weighted Least-Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares)

Comment: I incorporated a weightfunction in the residuals function and it works fine. I might take a look at the curve_fit routine, but since I'm actually using lmfit (which handles the parameters awesome) my first approach is the weighting.

Comment: Oh yes, I suppose you could do it that way -- in which case you could use `leastsq`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of doing this myself so I will share what I've done and perhaps we can get some comments from the community. I have a collection of data points taken at definite time intervals from which I've calculated standard deviations. I would like to fit these points with a sin function. Leastsq does this by minimizing the residual, or the difference between your data points and the fit function based on a set of parameters, p. We may weight our residuals by dividing them by the variance, or the square of the standard deviation.

As follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def sin_func(t, p):
    """ Returns the sin function for the parameters:
        p[0] := amplitude
        p[1] := period/wavelength
        p[2] := phase offset
        p[3] := amplitude offset
    """
    y = p[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi/p[1]*t+p[2])+p[3]
    return y

def sin_residuals(p, y, t, std):
    err = (y - p[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi/p[1]*t+p[2])-p[3])/std**2
    return err

def sin_fit(t, ydata, std, p0):
""" Fits a set of data, ydata, on a domain, t, with individual standard 
deviations, std, to a sin curve given the initial parameters, p0, of the form:
        p[0] := amplitude
        p[1] := period/wavelength
        p[2] := phase offset
        p[3] := amplitude offset
    """
    # optimization # 
    pbest = leastsq(sin_residuals, p0, args=(ydata, t, std), full_output=1)
    p_fit = pbest[0]

    # fit to data #
    fit = p_fit[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi/p_fit[1]*t+p_fit[2])+p_fit[3]

    return p_fit
```